# How can I parse this JSON?

Tags: php, html, json, parsing, url

I can't get the "img_url" (on third line) value from the JSON using PHP. Here's the JSON string:

**Edit (This is the JSON, my apologies for posting the var_dump)**:

```
{"status_code":200,"status_txt":"OK",
"data":{"img_name":"KdxIC.png","img_url":"http:\/\/s0.uploads.im\/KdxIC.png",
"img_view":"http:\/\/uploads.im\/KdxIC.png","img_width":"504","img_height":"504",
"img_attr":"width=\"504\" height=\"504\"","img_size":"15.1 KB","img_bytes":15494,
"thumb_url":"http:\/\/s0.uploads.im\/t\/KdxIC.png","thumb_width":360,"thumb_height":360,
"source":"http:\/\/site.com\/uploads\/icon1@2x.png","resized":"0","delete_key":"6e814d3c5201feee"}}
```

The accepted answer works. Thanks

Comment: Where are your attempted solutions?

Comment: I've never seen JSON that looked like that...What is returning this data?

Comment: That isn't JSON (it might be a dump of the results of `json_parsing` some JSON in PHP).

Comment: I've tried $json = json_decode($response, true); echo $json["data"]["img_url"]; and so on, but I always get nothing

Comment: it's response from uploads.im

Comment: sorry I didn't know it's not JSON, it seamed like JSON to me

Comment: Could you post the result of `echo $response`?

Comment: just FYI you can look at the basics of JSON at www.json.org

Comment: That looks like a `var_dump`, not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is not json, its a php dump of an array.

If you want to access the image url do this:
*I'm using this [example url](http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png).*

```
$imgdata = json_decode($response, true);
echo $imgdata["data"]["img_url"];
```

**Output:**

```
http://s0.uploads.im/go0WK.png
```

---

**Edit:**
*Do not use the second param in `json_decode`, that is converting your object to an array.*

Comment: How did you get the response? I'm using file_get_contents() but with no luck.

Comment: I tried this:
$img = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://uploads.im/api?upload=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo66.png'));
echo $img->data->img_url;
And it works great!

Comment: Thank you! Finally works all the way.